# how do i add padding by its surrounded area so it looks like a ripple?

Tags: css, reactjs, algorithm

I'm trying to add more padding to an array of elements that are in the same "zone" so it looks like a ripple. I couldn't figure out the math behind how to do this.

The input is an matrix but the current code seems a bit off and looks more of a circle.

any help would be appreciated

```
import React from 'react';

const DELTA = 20;

export function App(props) {
  const matrix = createEmptySquareMatrix(5);
  return (
    <div style = {{width: 500, height: 500, backgroundColor: "blue", justify: "center", alignItems: "center", display: "flex", flex: 1, flexDirection: "column"}}>
  <div style = {{bottom: -50}}>
    {matrix.map((matrixRow, rowIndex) => {
      console.log("rowIndex", rowIndex)
      return <div style = {{flexDirection: "row", display: "flex"}}>
      {matrixRow.map((matrixCol, colIndex) => {
        console.log("colIndex")
        return(
          <div style = {{
            paddingTop: topPadding(rowIndex, colIndex, 5) ? DELTA : 0,
            paddingLeft: leftPadding(rowIndex, colIndex, 5) ? DELTA : 0,
            paddingRight: rightPadding(rowIndex, colIndex, 5) ? DELTA : 0,
            paddingBottom: bottomPadding(rowIndex, colIndex, 5) ? DELTA : 0,}}>
            <Box />
          </div>
        )
      })
      }
      </div>
    })}
     

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function createEmptySquareMatrix(size){
    return Array(size).fill().map(()=>Array(size).fill())
}

function Box(){
  return(
    <div style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: "orange", margin:5}}/>
  )
}


function topPadding(row, col, size){
    return row <=Math.floor(size/2) && col >= row && col + row <=(size-1)
}

function leftPadding(row,col, size){
    return col <= Math.floor(size/2) && col <=row && col+row <=(size-1)
}
function rightPadding(row, col, size){
    return col >=Math.floor(size/2) && row <= col && col + row >=(size-1)
}

function bottomPadding(row, col, size){
    return row >=Math.floor(size/2) && row >= col && col + row >=(size-1)
}
```